# Fantasy Novel with 'Legacy' in the title about an Elf trader

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in on a deployment in Afghanistan. It came out of a MWR, and it had no cover, and most of the binding was ripped. The only surviving identifier was part of the title off the spine, which was 'Legacy (of, possibly)...' which I think was the first word. I'm guessing that it came out within the last 5-10 years, but without any title page, and a few other pages missing, I'm guessing since at least LOTR: FOTR came out (because it was a decent knock-off of the movie, not the book).

The story was about an Elf trader who is initially attacked and chased by Kobolds, only to be saved by a militia of Elves, in which the secondary protagonist is a swordsman of considerable skill. The kobolds want the trader because of his heritage; he is linked to an order of (human) knights who defied some deathlord necromancer who tried taking over the world some time before. The party eventually includes two dwarven brothers (one armed with a warhammer), a human thief (who is later bitten by a vampire), a female mage, a human prince/knight lancer, and another older male mage. They quest for some pretty important artifacts, the only one I really remember was some type of healing water from a pool that was heavily guarded by elven guards. There is a Three race council, which kobolds have an ambassador to, and the human ambassador ends up becoming a death knight after torturing and murdering his wife at some evil city. Throw in a mass zombie army, some betrayal, fantastic warriors and weapons, and some ghosts, and that's were the details I remember end.

Since I didn't know the author, I wanted to reread the book, and see if he/she had written any others.

Comment: This may seem like a strange question, but the dwarven brothers- was one of them a druid or at best semi-verbal?

Comment: One of the dwarven brothers was a a semi-hedonistic warrior. I think the other one might have been a druid/priest, or perhaps more religiously inclined. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by semi-verbal; he neither had any vows of silence, nor was he an idiot. The only thing I really remember about them was that the warrior brother carried a warhammer that had a beak/spike contraption that came up more than a few times. They were nobility as well, pretty high up in the pecking order.

Comment: I was thinking it might have been a Forgotten Realms book, since several of them feature dwarven brothers- one more "classically" dwarven (either a hammer or an axe, lots of fighting and beer), the other an (initially) aspiring druid who could barely speak.  I recall their names being Ivan and Pickle, respectively.

Comment: It wasn't Forgotten Realms, for it definately didn't mention any locations that I can recall. I thought this too at first, but the book, whie paperback, was much larger than your average book, 6x10 perhaps? Plus the feel of the book itself didn't suggest Tor or WotC (I'm an avid reader, and yes, you can tell a book by its' feel. Try it if you don't believe me!) I would say that it was a single publication (stand-alone) and definately not one of the bigger publishers. It was probably one of the ones where some guy spent 5 years writing it and 5 grand of his own money getting it published.

Comment: Eh, it was worth a shot.

Comment: I get it and appreciate it. I've loooked for this book for a while, including bookstores and internet. It just sucks that it didn't even have a cover to get an idea, and no title on the tops of the pages or anything. It's like trying to solve Edwin Drood's mystery! (LitRefHumor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. Finally.

The Piaras Legacy by Scott Gamboe.

> Long ago, so the legends say, the Necromancer Volnor invaded the continent of Pelacia. His legions of undead soldiers ravaged the land unchecked, until the three nations united and pushed their evil foes back into the Desert of Malator. But that was centuries ago, and few people still believe the tale. Other, more worldly matters occupy their time, such as recent attacks by renegade Kobolds. But Elac, an elf who makes his way as a merchant, is too concerned with his business affairs to become involved in international politics—until a marauding band of Kobolds attack Elac's caravan and he finds himself running for his life. Befriended by an elfin warrior named Rilen, he travels to Unity, the seat of power on the Pelacian continent. There he is joined by a diverse group of companions, and he sets out on an epic quest to solve the riddle of his heritage and save the land from the growing evil that threatens to engulf it.